# Need help to resolve the issue ... not getting desired output. I would like to input two bank details and want output for the same

Tags: java

I am new to Java and stared learning things of my own, however I need some help to resolve the issue I am facing... let me know where I am wrong with my code.

My output is displaying like

```
Input -
Enter Bank Name: a
Enter Bank Account number: 1
Output - 
Bank Name: null
Bank Account Number: 0
```

Why it is not displaying bank name as 'a' and account number as '1'. Kindly provide some help.

```
//Bank.java

import java.util.Scanner;
class Bank
{
    String bank_name;
    int bank_account_number;

    void input_info()
    {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Bank Name: "); 
        String bank_name = input1.nextLine();

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Bank Account number: ");
        int bank_account_number = input2.nextInt();
    }

    void display_info()
    {
        System.out.println("Bank Name: " +bank_name);
        System.out.println("Bank Account Number: " +bank_account_number);
    }
}
```

---

```
//Display_bank_details.java

class Display_bank_details
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Bank details1 = new Bank();
        Bank details2 = new Bank();

        details1.input_info();
        details2.input_info();

        details1.display_info();
        details2.display_info();
    }

}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you don't need both `input1` and `input2`. Just keep using the first one.

Comment: look closely at yout method `input_info()` - then you should find it.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is the scoping of your variables. In your `input_info` method, you have these lines:

```
String bank_name = input1.nextLine();
...
int bank_account_number = input2.nextInt();
```

Those are declaring *local* variables that only exist in the method. Instead, you want to assign new values to the *fields* in your object. It's an easy change to make:

```
// Just assignments, not declarations
bank_name = input1.nextLine();
...
bank_account_number = input2.nextInt();
```

Additionally, I would:

- Rename the variables and methods to follow Java naming conventions, e.g. `inputInfo`, `displayInfo`
- Remove the `bank` prefix from the variables - you're already in a `Bank` class, so just `name` and `accountNumber` should be fine (although the latter suggests it should be a `BankAccount` rather than a `Bank`
- Create a *single* `Scanner` object and pass that as an argument to the `inputInfo` method, rather than creating a new one for each line of input

Comment: Thank You so much Jeroen Steenbeeke and Jon Skeet. That really solved my issue.

Comment: BTW, @Jon Skeet, I will learn about your #3rd point "Create a single Scanner object and pass that as an argument ..." and will update my code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you're doing something which is called "hiding". You're creating new variables with the same name as your class fields inside your methods.

```
    String bank_name = input1.nextLine();
    int bank_account_number = input2.nextInt();
```

Remove the types on these lines and you'll be assigning the values to your fields instead.